# Is there any way to align the text written to a text file?

Tags: android, eclipse, excel

For my application I am pulling words from a database and writing them to a text file. The file is then emailed to someone else as a time card. The problem is the varying sizes, a lot of the dates and text can be a little big. Also if they open the docs in say excel or Works Spreadsheet, they have to tediously expand the cells of the larger texts by hand. So is there anyway to align the text better or automatically expand the cells? Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: If you send text, they get text. If you attach the info as a CSV file it can then be imported into most spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps overly simplistic, but a rather portable option would be making your text file HTML and using a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)